# Adding custom fields (post meta) before/during wp_insert_post()

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, wp-insert-post, hacks

Our code base has a ton of logic that executes as the post is inserted/created. However, some of that logic depends on custom post meta. The only way I know of to add post meta to a new post is like so:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_obj);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'key', "value");
```

However, this means that the post meta is not present when hooks on post insertion happen.

Is there any way to set up or include post meta as part of `$post_obj`?

I tried making up new properties of the post object with `$post_obj->custom_key = 'value'` but it didn't seem to actually end up in the database. The only thing I can think of is to hijack an existing property of the post object that I'm not using, like `menu_order`, and store some information there. That's an ugly hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook your function to the [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) action hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse128767_add_meta' );
function wpse128767_add_meta( $post_id ) {
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', 'value' );
}
```

To make sure your metadata has been added before any other insert hooks run, give it a higher priority:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse128767_add_meta', 1 );
```

By default `add_action()` uses a priority of `10`; the lower the number, the earlier it runs.

Comment: The problem is that the post meta needs to be added conditionally, not every time we add a post. `wp_insert_post()` is being triggered from a dashboard widget, and in that case we need this metadata. When `wp_insert_post()` is called normally from other places, we don't want that metadata. Is there any way to sort of pass logic to an action like `wpse128767_add_meta`?

Comment: Hmm. Is there anything in the existing post data to indicate that the source of the insert is the dashboard widget? It might be helpful if you could edit your question to include the relevant code from the widget.

Comment: Nevermind, this is the correct answer. The key, of course, is to not call `add_action()` in functions.php or some other globally loaded file, but only call it from the same piece of code that needs this functionality. For a moment I was thinking that `add_action()` would somehow save it globally and be called on every `wp_insert_post` action in our entire WordPress installation, which of course is not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```php
//Your args to Gather post data.
$args = array(
    'post_title'    => 'My post',
    'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
);


//Retrieve Id back after new post is made.
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args, true );

//Check for errors, before updating meta fields
 if (is_wp_error($post_id)):
        $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
        foreach ($errors as $error):
            //log errors
            echo $error;
        endforeach;
 else:

   //If updating WP meta
   update_post_meta( $post_id, meta_key1, 'add this');
   update_post_meta( $post_id, meta_key2, 'add something');

   //if updating ACF meta
   //update_field( 'meta_key1', 'add this', $post_id );
   //update_field( 'meta_key2', 'add something', $post_id );
 
 endif;
```